# sql messages table query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

this is my conversation table:

```
conversationID  ||  userID
      1         ||    1
      1         ||    2
      2         ||    1
      2         ||    2
      2         ||    3
```

as you can see each conversation can contain 2 users or more.

I am trying to get the id of the conversation that only 2 users are there.
ie conversation that contains only users 1 & 2, the answer is conversation 1.

but how do I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will select all conversations that have users 1 or user 2, or both, but no one else:

```
select conversationID
from conversations
group by conversationID
having count(*) = count(case when userID in (1,2) then 1 end)
```

If you also want all conversations that have exactly user 1 and 2, and no one else, you also have to add an and condition:

```
select conversationID
from conversations
group by conversationID
having count(*) = count(case when userID in (1,2) then 1 end)
       and count(*) = 2 -- number of elements in set
```

If userID can be duplicated, it's also better to use distinct:

```
select conversationID
from conversations
group by conversationID
having
  count(distinct userID) = count(distinct case when userID in (1,2) then userID end)
  and count(distinct userID) = 2 -- number of elements in set
```

Comment: +1 I like this approach, and I don't think I've seen it before. It would extend well to an analytic function that returns the complete sets of rows as well.

Comment: Further thought: I think that one potential improvement would be to eliminate conversations before the group by, especially if there are a great many conversations in which 1 and 2 are not involved. So if you added a clause along the lines of "where conversationid in (select conversationid from conversations where userid = 1)" (hopefully using the less chatty user somehow) then it could be a significant aid to scaling the query.

Comment: @DavidAldridge thanks! i updated my answer, the first query would return a conversation even if one of the elements in set does not exist, and i am not sure this is what the OP wants... second (and third) query should handle this correctly

Answer (score 2):

You should use having clause. Assuming that ( conversationID, userID ) is PK or AK, your query is:

```
  select   conversationID
    from   your_Table
group by   conversationID
  having   count( * ) = 2
```

**Edited** Joined with 1,2 user conversations, this is the index friendly approach with out correlate subquery and without function by row.

```
      select   t1 conversationID
        from   your_Table t1
  inner join 
               ( select distinct conversationID
                  from your_Table
                 where userId in (1, 2)
               ) t2
          on   t1.conversationID = t2.conversationID
    group by   t1.conversationID
      having   count( distinct t1.userId ) = 2
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think OP wants conversations that only **specific** 2 users are there

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps you,

```
select conversationID from conversation
group by ConversationID having count(distinct UserID)=2;
```

[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c775/16)

Comment: Ah, that would be conversations in which only two users participate, not two specific users