# How to create a "Read Message" query from table messages and messages viewed?

Tags: mysql, database, left-join, inner-join

I would like to get the messages that someone hasnt read... it could be a count o just a "1" if there are pending messages to read.

The trick is that there are many " users" shareing the same system. So if I usear "A" reads a message from the table then the notification wont appear anymore to A, but for "B" there should be a notification of pending messages. They are sharing the same message lets say.

I create a query that works somehow , but I know is not 100% right.

I did review

[Querying conversations from messages table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43341179/querying-conversations-from-messages-table)

[sql messages table query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905000/sql-messages-table-query)

In the example below is the deal.

"A" last viewbymessage for the docid 93 was on 2019-01-28 10:02:15, then user B send a new message BUT never reads the message sent by "A",  so in my query, "A" will never be able to see there was a new message since he was the last to see if, and I not using the MessageTable only the Messages_View .. I know this is the wrong part, but im just stating how I used to have it.

SELECT B.*
FROM Comments_Viewed_Tbl B LEFT JOIN Comments_Viewed_Tbl C

ON (B.DOCID =C.DOCID and B.Date_Viewed < C.Date_Viewed)

WHERE C.Date_Viewed IS NULL and B.viewedby <>'A' and

B.RPDOC = 93 and B.Country ='USA'

*sorry for the image, I did try to put it as text but the system format irt ugly

[image: Image Table]

How would be the best approach to do the query.

In this scenario A should have an alert or counter of the new message as also B since he/she didnt check it and just send a new one.

Answer (score 0):

So adding a comment is the same as sending a message?

From my point of view, you need to add the CommentID column to the Comments_Viewed_Tbl, otherwise you will never be able to see the read status of each specific comment, only for the whole document.

Otherwise you will need to assume that the last person to add a comment to the document has read all previous comments.

Comment: Yes, adding a new comment is the same as sending. I thought kind of the same because of a friend told me that idea, but is it really the only way? I mean I got a date and time of the last message seen by A and they are joined by the doc and country  so i was wondering if that would be enought like to get the last message date from that group on that user, and from that point check vs the new messages that are not of that user based on the comment date input. I know sounds like mess , but just thinking out loud.